# WebStorm shows all project files deleted as unstaged changes to commit

Tags: git, github, terminal, webstorm, commit

I am working in WebStorm, not sure if it's WebStorm or Git issue.

I have only changed 3 files, the changes normally show only them. Once I leave the IDE, then come back and I see the whole project (1127 files) as deleted in the changes.

When I try to reset to head it rolls everything back to 3 files, waiting 5 min and all the 'deleted' files are there again. It is an infinite loop of despair.

I've tried resetting to head, it helps for 5 min and all over again.

Comment: Are you storing your repository in any sort of unusual file system?  Is it being synced with a cloud syncing service (e.g., iCloud or Dropbox) or on a network file system of any kind?  Also, what OS and version are you using?

Comment: It sounds like the files are actually getting deleted during that 5 mins, and Git is simply telling you that this is happening. If you see the files are actually gone, and resetting in Git brings them back, then this isn't a Git issue and you need to figure out what is deleting them.

Comment: @bk2204 That actually makes so much sense! Haven't thought of it. My mac sync everything to iCloud that is supposed to be the issue
Thank you!!

Comment: but what is the problem to store the files in iCloud? I have this same issue, time to time my project in webstorm looses git "connection"...I need to restore the backup from Time Machine. My files are stored in iCloud. Does anyone know how to fix it and still using webstorm files in iCloud?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac it might be because you keep your project in the place where it syncs it with the cloud.

Try cloning the project into a place like ~/dev/project_name