# PhpStorm with Git shows thousand of changed file every couple of minutes

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm experiencing a strange issue in the last couple of months with PHP + Git. While working on some local branch every couple of mins (sometimes it more random an less aggressive) PhpStorm will show all my monorepo files changed. Like so:

[image]

The only way to temporarily fix this situation is do `git add .` and push my changes to the branch ASAP. But then it might happen again several min later.

My PhpStorm version is:

```
Build #PS-232.8660.205, built on July 28, 2023
```

Couldn't find an proper solution.

Comment: What does your `.gitignore` look like? What do the actual changes look like? Post a diff of one or two files and show what `git status` outputs for you. The files seem sensible to be committed. But I wander what `packages/` is. Is that an external package installed with npm or composer (that should be in the .gitignore)? Or are they custom functionality added by you? If you suspect a PHPStorm bug, check JetBrains' issue tracker.

Comment: @LazyOne The changes are as if the files are deleted.
`packages/` is where the monorepo lives, all src code is there.
`.gitignore` looks like so: [link](https://pastebin.com/3D57PxLk)

Comment: @nragonnragon 1) What is your OS? 2) Are you keeping this project in a some folder that is synced to Cloud (e.g. OneDrive/DropBox or alike). For me this does not look like an IDE issue, but rather your OS / other apps. Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77921890/783119 . If that's so -- try moving your files to another location and check how it will behave there.

Comment: @LazyOne 
1) OS: macOS Sonoma v14.1.1
2) I guess you are right it seems like my ICloud is configured to backup Desktop files and this is exactly where my project is currently stored. I'll play around little bit and let you know :)

Comment: @LazyOne Yeah that seems to be the case, Thank you!